# Get input script from EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I usually have short `bash` scripts that run once I spin up an EC2 server. Sometimes this happens through the Web AWS console. Is there some way I can find those scripts from the EC2 instance's shell? I would rather not have to reconstruct it through `history`, I presume `history` has to be command number - limited by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just typing `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` should do it! `169.254.169.254` is a link-local I.P for EC2 instances that helps with querying for this stuff.